# How to install connectors to the docker image of apache kafka connect

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using  https://hub.docker.com/r/1ambda/kafka-connect/ to install docker kafka connect on ubuntu .I am able to run it but ,I am unable to install any more connectors in it.

What I have tried

1-I tried  copying the connector files from my machine to the docker containers connector folder and restarting but the api ,http://localhost:8080/connectors give empty array.

2-Also added plugin path in connect-distributed.properties .
How to do this any idea ??

Answer (score 4):

## Solution without using Confluent Hub

### Step 1: Build your own Kafka-Connect image

Your directory should look like this:

```
my-directory /
  Dockerfile
  plugins /
    my-connector /
       <connector-jars>
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect-base:latest
USER root:root
COPY ./plugins/ /opt/kafka/plugins/
ENV CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH="/opt/kafka/plugins"
USER 1001
```

Run the following

```bash
cd /my-directory
sudo docker build . -t my-connector-image-name
```

### Step 2: Use the created image for your kafka-connect container

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
        zookeeper:
                container_name: 'zookeeper'
                image: 'bitnami/zookeeper:latest'
                ports:
                        - '2181:2181'
                environment:
                        - ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN=yes
        kafka:
                image: 'bitnami/kafka:latest'
                container_name: 'kafka'
                ports:
                        - '9092:9092'
                environment:
                        - KAFKA_BROKER_ID=1
                        - KAFKA_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://:9092
                        - KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://192.168.178.70:9092
                        - KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
                        - ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER=yes
                depends_on:
                        - zookeeper
        kafka-connect:
                image: 'my-connector-image-name:latest'
                container_name: 'kafka-connect'
                ports:
                        - '8083:8083'
                environment:
                        - CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=kafka:9092
                        - CONNECT_REST_PORT=8083
                        - CONNECT_GROUP_ID=quickstart
                        - CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=quickstart-config
                        - CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=quickstart-offsets
                        - CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=quickstart-status
                        - CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
                        - CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
                        - CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR=1
                        - CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
                        - CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
                        - CONNECT_INTERNAL_KEY_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
                        - CONNECT_INTERNAL_VALUE_CONVERTER=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
                        - CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=localhost
                depends_on:
                        - kafka
```

### Step 3 Get available Connector Plugins

`curl localhost:8083/connector-plugins | json_pp`

> Side note on my Kafka configuration: I'm hosting Docker inside a Linux
> virtual machine that I've assigned IP 192.168.178.70.

Answer (score 1):

That image does not appear to be updated to work with `plugin.path` since it is using Kafka 0.10

You could use `confluent-hub` to install connectors like I have documented in my Connect container

https://github.com/OneCricketeer/apache-kafka-connect-docker

Comment: you probably dont have mysql jar in kafka connect .I have already tried this

Comment: @gANDALF I don't because it is not Apache Licensed

Comment: @gANDALF That wasn't part of your question, though, and using my image doesn't prevent you from installing `kafka-connect-jdbc` and copying into it's installation directory

Answer (score 0):

> 1-I tried copying the connector files from my machine to the docker containers connector folder and restarting but the api ,http://localhost:8080/connectors give empty array.

localhost:8083/connectors , will give you the list of active connectors.
If you need to check the list of available plugins you should hit localhost:8083/connector-plugins

```
curl localhost:8083/connector-plugins
[{"class":"io.confluent.connect.activemq.ActiveMQSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.5.1"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"5.5.1"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.ibm.mq.IbmMQSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.5.1"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"5.5.1"},
{"class":"io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.5.1"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.jms.JmsSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.5.1"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"5.5.1"},{"class":"io.confluent.connect.storage.tools.SchemaSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.5.1-ccs"},{"class":"io.confluent.kafka.connect.datagen.DatagenConnector","type":"source","version":"null"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSinkConnector","type":"sink","version":"5.5.1-ccs"}, 
{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.file.FileStreamSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"5.5.1-ccs"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorCheckpointConnector","type":"source","version":"1"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorHeartbeatConnector","type":"source","version":"1"},{"class":"org.apache.kafka.connect.mirror.MirrorSourceConnector","type":"source","version":"1"}]
```

Also, a new connector needs to be added to the mentioned plugin-path of all your worker nodes and a restart is required for all

To further troubleshoot you can try increasing the loglevel to DEBUG and check the startup logs if the connector path is being traversed
You will see a log with the following format :

```
DEBUG Loading plugin urls: ......
```

Hope this helps resolve your issue :)