# when you use kafka(in docker container), Where exactly is the plugin path?

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-kafka-connect

----- i use kafka, kafka-connect(image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect)

when you use kafka in docker container   if you wanna operate kafka, you have to go into  the container(like 'docker exec -it kafka' or 'docker exec -it kafka-connect' ----> this is another question what i wanna ask) , right..??

i tried putting some connector (jdbc connector, mysql connector) into kafka-connect container, but it didn't work.

so.. my question is

1. after docker-compose up(put in container), if i wanna connect with some connectors('./bin/connect-distributed.sh ./etc/kafka/connect-distributed.properties'),
   what container i have to go into???
2. if i type plugin path, where should i write?( kafka? kafka-connect?)

I wouldn't mind if it was difficult to read... sorry for that

Comment: Can you detail, what is your requirement? You need start up the specific Connect o you need interacts with the kafka CLI tools such as kafka-topics.sh, kafka-consumer-groups.sh, and others?

Answer (score 0):

No, you don't need to exec anywhere unless you cannot download Kafka on your host machine to get the CLI scripts. But you'd only exec for `kafka-topics`, console producer/consumer, `kafka-consumer-groups`, etc, not any of the Connect scripts.

The Connect container automatically runs the Distributed script and you simply provide `CONNECT_PLUGIN_PATH` as an environment variable to any directory in the container you want to use for the plugins (I like `/opt/connectors` if I mount volume, but that's not where `confluent-hub` installs to for that image). That variable doesn't do anything for the broker image, only Connect.

Related [How to install connectors to the docker image of apache kafka connect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63172483/how-to-install-connectors-to-the-docker-image-of-apache-kafka-connect)

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is startup a Kafka Connect.

You can use the basic guide published by Confluent ["Build Your Own Apache Kafka® Demos"](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/tutorials/build-your-own-demos.html?utm_source=github&utm_medium=demo&utm_campaign=ch.examples_type.community_content.cp-all-in-one#build-your-own-demos-onprem-cp)

Basically you need execute the following instructions:

```
git clone https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one.git
cd cp-all-in-one/cp-all-in-one
git checkout 7.1.1-post
docker-compose up -d
```

This has Control Center at http://localhost:8088

If you need install a Connector, you can go to the https://www.confluent.io/hub select your specific connector.

Then, you  can create your DockerImage of specific Kafka Connect server.

1.- Write a Dockerfile.

```
vim Dockerfile
```

2.-  Add connector "example JDBC" from Confluent Hub.

```
FROM confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect
ENV MYSQL_DRIVER_VERSION 5.1.39
RUN confluent-hub install --no-prompt confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc:10.5.0
RUN curl -k -SL "https://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-J/mysql-connector-java-${MYSQL_DRIVER_VERSION}.tar.gz" \
     | tar -xzf - -C /usr/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-jdbc/lib \
     --strip-components=1 mysql-connector-java-5.1.39/mysql-connector-java-${MYSQL_DRIVER_VERSION}-bin.jar
```

3.- Build the docker image.

```
docker build . -t my-kafka-connect-jdbc:1.0.0
```

4.- Then, you can go to edit your docker-compose.yml, change the line 57

from:

```
image: cnfldemos/cp-server-connect-datagen:0.5.3-7.1.0
```

to:

```
image: my-kafka-connect-jdbc:1.0.0
```

5.- Finally, stop and start your Confluent Platform local environment:

```
docker-compose down
docker-compose up
```

Verify your docker

```
docker ps
```

Test your Connect server:

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:8083/connectors'
```

Comment: You don't need to clone a git repo. The images are all available to pull from Docker hub. Or download only the compose file from github. And I don't think this really answered where plugins are stored or how to actually create a connector